# Unable to import ROS2 custom message to Node header file in different packages C++

Tags: ros2

I'm new to developing ROS2 in c++, but have experience in Python side of things. I've created a separate package for custom messages, with the required CMakeLists  for the CustomMessage Package. Now I've created another ROS2 C++ package, and am trying to import the message to an Header file, but ROS2 shows an no such file or directory.

name of the custom message package: map_messages

**CUSTOM MSG** -> HDMapBin.msg

```
uint8 MAP_FORMAT_LANELET2=0

std_msgs/Header header

uint8 map_format
string format_version
string map_version

std_msgs/UInt8[] values
```

map_messages Package CMAKELST

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(map_messages)

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake_auto REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(builtin_interfaces REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)

ament_auto_find_build_dependencies()

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/HDMapBin.msg"
  "msg/HDMapSegment.msg"
  "msg/HDMapPrimitive.msg"
  "msg/HDMapRoute.msg"
  DEPENDENCIES
    "std_msgs"
    "geometry_msgs"
    "builtin_interfaces"
  ADD_LINTER_TESTS
)
ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()

endif()

ament_auto_package()
```

Now I import this into a separate package, and already put the required things into CMakeLists of the secondary package like `find_package(map_messages REQUIRED)`, and import the message as 'map_messages/msg/hd_map_bin.hpp` [naming convention according to what I found under the build folder of ROS2 WS.

Once I build the same, ros2 gives me the following error
`map_messages/msg/hd_map_bin.hpp: No such file or directory`

any fix for this??

Answer (score 2):

Your guess for the naming convention was nearly correct.

If you package is named in CamelCase: `"msg/HDMapBin.msg"`

Then every uppercase letter will indicate a new word for the message generator.

That means `HDMapBin.msg` -> `h_d_map_bin.hpp`

You should include:

```cpp
#include map_messages/msg/h_d_map_bin.hpp
```

And of course you should add the dependecy in your CMakeList.txt file to the install target

```
find_package(map_messages REQUIRED)

ament_target_dependencies(cpp_node
   rclcpp
   map_messages
)
```